# Create a list of all matched strings without duplicates

Tags: grep

I have a list of urls that look like:

```
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page3
```

From this, I want to create a list that's like:

```
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page3
```

So if there are more than one match, I want to return only one of the matches. What would the grep pattern be for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily do it using `awk`

```
$ awk '!url[$0]++' input
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page3
```